# home directory changed

Tags: 18.04, home-directory

I changed the location of the home directory to a different disk, making changes to fstab but lost information on downloads and old images, is there any way to recover the old home directory or  some old images and download files?

Comment: If you copied your old home directory to the other disk, the old home will still be there. Just `sudo umount` the partition that your home directory is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not erase the data, it will still be available on your old location. However, it is "hidden" because the other partition is mounted on the /home folder. If you unmount the partition coupled to /home, the old contents will become visible.

The only issue is that you cannot unmount a home partition while you are logged in to the graphical environment. So you either will need to work from a recovery prompt, or from a live session of an installation DVD/USB if you prefer a graphical working environment.